# Task-specific background

Tags: conemu

Can I define the background of ConEmu to be specific to a given task? As per the [documentation](https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html) this should be possible using `-new_console:W:"wallpaper"` but when I do that, my tabs still have the regular white background.

Context: I have set up two ConEmu tasks: they both run Powershell but each runs it as a different user. I would like to get an "all-in-your-face visual cue" (as mentioned in the comments [here](https://superuser.com/a/518384/253952)): in tabs of task1, the background should be white, in tabs of task2 it should be light green.

I've created an all-green PNG image and I did `-new_console:W:"C:\temp\green.png"` but the background remains white.

Comment: Wallpaper must be enabled in common settings. Without your xml and exact example I can't say more.

Comment: Thanks, I've figured it now. It's what you said (the wallpaper had to be enabled) plus I needed to figure out "Replace color indexes" in the Background setting because I had a custom colorscheme applied.